# can i Validate access tokens sent by third-party OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server in wso2 api manger while calling API

Tags: wso2

I have a requirement that I need to validate 3rd party Authorization Server access token in `wso2` API manager. If token active and valid then allow resource

Answer (score 0):

imho as the simplest solution you could build a custom inbound mediation flow  for that (if you are familiar with wso2 esb mediations). For this option you will loose some apim capabilities (throttling, authorization, analytics)

you should aware the default authorization handler would clean the Authorization header (as far I know) , so you may need to add a custom handler to preserve the original  header value